# eTrex 10 UTC or GMT time zone

Tags: time, garmin

I have an eTrex 10. I'd like my GPS to remain in UTC (or GMT) time zone, but it does not offer this option as far as I can tell. I think "[Western European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time)" and "Ignore DST" is equivalent to GMT. Is this the best or only way to have data on this device recorded as close to UTC as possible?

Comment: Nope: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time

Comment: To my experience with other Garmin models, timestamps are always recorded in UTC, regardless of the time zone used for display purposes only.